# AnyDesk TCP tunnelling port "closed" since Windows 10 2004

Tags: firewall, hyper-v, remote-desktop, tunneling, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I connect to my company computer via AnyDesk. I have [set up a TCP tunnel](https://support.anydesk.com/TCP-Tunneling) from local port 11111 to remote port 22, to have an SSH connection to the remote machine.

This stopped working since I installed Windows 10 2004 and WSL 2 on the client, a few days ago:

```
$ ssh remoteuser@127.0.0.1 -p 11111
ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 11111: Connection refused

$ nmap localhost -p 11111

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-05-30 21:13 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000048s latency).

PORT      STATE  SERVICE
11111/tcp closed vce

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.03 seconds
```

I suspect that this has to do with WSL 2, which I read uses Hyper-V, which messes with network configuration (there are new Hyper-V network adapters that I can monitor in Task Manager). I would like to avoid uninstalling WSL 2 if possible, and downgrading to Windows 10 1909 is not an option.

Why is the AnyDesk TCP tunnelling port closed?